# REST API - filters not working inside plugin class

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, rest-api

I have this code inside  plugin I'm writing. I need to add some filters to customize WP REST API anyway I'm noticing that filters seems not working

```php
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class Microservices {
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', array( $this, 'set_rest_api_prefix' ) );
        //add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', array( $this, 'check_user_authentication' ) );
        //
        //add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'extend_default_routes' ) );
        //add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'extend_default_rest_fields' ) );
    }

    /*
    *
    */
    public function set_rest_api_prefix()
    {
        return 'api';
    }

    /*
    *
    */
    public function extend_default_routes() 
    {
        //register_rest_route( 
        //    'extranet/', 
        //    'v1/login', 
        //    array(
        //        'methods' => 'POST'
        //    ), 
        //    true 
        //);
        register_rest_route( 
            'extranet/', 
            'v1/userDetails', 
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'get_logged_user_info' )
            ), 
            false 
        );
        //
        register_rest_route( 
            'extranet/', 
            'v1/sendComunication', 
            array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'send_new_comunication' )
            ), 
            false 
        );
        //
        register_rest_route(
            'extranet/',
            'v1/loadArchive',
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'load_files_archive' )
            )
        );
        //
        register_rest_route( 
            'extranet/', 
            'v1/createFolder', 
            array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'create_new_folder' )
            ), 
            false 
        );
        //
        register_rest_route(
            'extranet/',
            'v1/uploadFiles',
            array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'upload_new_files' )
            ),
            false
        );

    } 
    
    /*
    *
    */
    public function extend_default_rest_fields()
    {
        //register_rest_field( 
        //    $object_type:string|array, 
        //    $attribute:string, 
        //    $args:array 
        //);
    }

    /*
    *
    */
    public function check_user_authentication( $result ) 
    {
        // If a previous authentication check was applied,
        // pass that result along without modification.
        if( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            return $result;
        }

        // No authentication has been performed yet.
        // Return an error if user is not logged in.
        if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return new WP_Error(
                'rest_not_logged_in',
                __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
                array( 'status' => 403 )
            );
        }

        // Our custom authentication check should have no effect
        // on logged-in requests
        return $result;
    }
}

new Microservices();
```

I've tried to call the renamed api from postman in my dev machine using localhost, but it will result in a 404, but the wp-json still work. The plugin is active, so what's the problem with the code?

Comment: Is this code in the main plugin file? Or included separately in some way?

Comment: It's in the èlugin file. I've noticed that I had a typo into the __constructor, but I'm still unable to remove  `wp-json` as default wordpress api prefix

Comment: Your `check_user_authentication` is doing the work that a `permission_callback` is intended to do, WordPress will be generating deprecation warnings in your error log due to the lack of a `permission_callback` ( it's not optional ). Have you tried flushing permalinks/rewrite rules?

Comment: @TomJNowell not tested yet, I've done the flushing permalink operation

Comment: @ICTDEV I see `extend_default_routes` is not called, the filter that adds it is commented out, I also see the `__contruct` vs `__construct` mistake is still present in the code

Comment: @TomJNowell typo fixed

Comment: @ICTDEV the code still has the `add_filter` call for `extend_default_routes` commented out, which is why that route is giving you a 404

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```php
public function __contruct()
```

it should be `__construct`, the S is missing, meaning there is no constructor and the `add_filter` calls never happen

The function that registers the routes also never runs because the `add_action` call is commented out:

```php
//add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'extend_default_routes' ) );
```

This means the constructor never runs, and if it did run the `extend_default_routes` function would never be called, so the routes are never registered.

Comment: I've solved that typo, but if I try to reach my custom endpoint using `localhost/sits/api/extranet/v1/loadArchive` for example, also if I disable the authentication check, I will get a 404 from postman

Comment: did you flush permalinks too? i'ma ssuming `/sits/` is where your WordPress install is? Have you tried adding a `permission_callback` and setting it to `__return_true` then testing this without the additional authentication filter that was added? There's not much point validating an authenticated request if we can't confirm the endpoint exists to begin with. It also looks like you commented out the filters that add your endpoints. Can you update your question with the latest code if you've made fixes?

Comment: I've updated the code to disable the authentication check. And yes, `sits` is the folder under localhost where I've installed wordpress